# pass a keyvalue to my innerloop

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-view, zend-framework3

In my view I want to show 2 recordsets, like this:

```
    <?php 
//var_dump(get_object_vars($projects));
foreach ($projects as $project) : 
//var_dump(get_object_vars($project));

?>
    <tr>
    <td><?= $project['Projectname']?></td>
    <td><?= $project['ProjectShortcut']?></td>
    <td><?= $project['ProjectCiNumber']?></td>
    <td><?= $project['Unitname']?></td>
    <td><?= $project['UnitShortcut']?></td>
    <td><?= $project['UnitCiNumber']?></td>
    <td>
            <a href="<?= $this->url('import', ['action' => 'edit', 'id' => $import->DCLID]) ?>">Edit</a>
            <a href="<?= $this->url('import', ['action' => 'delete', 'id' => $import->DCLID]) ?>">Delete</a>
        </td>

<?php   foreach ($dcls as $dcl) : ?>
    <td><?= $this->Path?></td>
    <td><?= $this->UnitID?></td>
    <td><?= $this->Importdate?></td>
    </tr>


  <?php     endforeach;

  endforeach; ?
```

How can I pass the keyvalue UnitID to the inner loop? I want to show all units, that works already and underneath the imports belonging to the unit.

Here also how I pass the data to the view from within my controller:

```
return new ViewModel([
            'projects' => $this->projectTable->fetchAll(),
                'dcls' => $this->table->fetchAll()
                ]);
```

somehow in the ViewModel or in the view I want to give a parameter UnitID to the dcl collection.

So my questions would be, where shall I do it, probably in my view? And how might be the exact syntax?

Comment: could you explain, what is `UnitID` data exactly? And also give the example `key value`

Comment: it is of course a foreignkey value which is integer